# Solution to relative path to image in CSS file depending on what file that includes it

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have a filestructure:

```
index.html
css/styles.css
images/paper.gif
subfolder/index.html
```

css file called styles.css, located in a folder called **css/styles.css** containing

```
.image{
    background-image: url("images/paper.gif");
    background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

If I include this file in a index.html located in root directory the image will show.

Now lets say I have another folder called subfolder/index.html and want to inlcude that css **../css/styles.css** file then that url to the image wont work since the css file is expecting that there would be a folder called images in "subfolder" with a file in it. So in order to avoid having to declare 2 classes containing the same code, is there another way of dealing with this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have to keep everything separately?

Comment: A path in a .css file within `url()` is always relative to the destination of its .css file. I don't see a problem with your example here, as long as the images are always stored in the very same folder.
`background-image: url("../images/paper.gif");` should work just fine here.

Comment: @PhilM. that works in `subfolder/index.html` but not in the root `index.html`

Comment: @PhilM. is right: the OP's premise is incorrect. if the stylesheet is __/css/styles.css__, then `url("images/paper.gif")` in the stylesheet always means __/css/images/paper.gif__, no matter which html file the stylesheet is called up from.

Comment: Thanks @MrLister. That's what I meant when I said the `url()` inside the .css file uses relative paths to its own path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is with absolute paths. This means that in your CSS you must define an absolute path for your images, for example:

```
 background-image: url(/images/image.png);
```

What's the problem? You need to know the absolute path where your folders are. For example, if you have this URL: `http://localhost/myFolder/images/image.png`, your CSS will be:

```
 background-image: url(/myFolder/images/image.png);
```

But when you upload it to a production server like this: `http://myserver.com/images/image.png`, your CSS must to change to something like this:

```
 background-image: url(/images/image.png);
```

So the best way is to develop in the same environment that your production server. This will be with the URL `http://localhost/images/image.png` (develop) and `http://myserver.com/images/image.png` (production).

Another way is to making friendly URLs, that avoids to you to make custom folders, and you can have all in one folder and the URLs will be rewrited by the server.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It should work for root and sub folders index file..

```
.image{
background-image: url("../images/paper.gif");
background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

But check path of included CSS in Index file.

it should be For Root index file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

and for sub folder index file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, because the OP's assumption "url to the image wont work since the css file is expecting that there would be a folder called images in subfolder with a file in it" was incorrect.